# How to resign first responder when entering currency

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter, uitextfielddelegate, resignfirstresponder

I'd like to make my text field resign first responder after the cents are entered in a text field for entering currency. I'm using `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` so only numerals are entered. When the second numeral after the decimal point is entered I want the text field to resign first responder.

1

12

123

123.4

123.45 *now resign first responder*.

Do I have the delegate compare the text to the regular expression `*\...` for each `textDidChange` notification? Starting counting when `.` is entered?

Is there a way to apply `NSNumberFormatter` and `setMaximumFractionDigits:2` to the text input field?

Comment: AFAIK UITextField does not have that option, so you've got the right idea with the delegate.  However, this behavior seems like it could create a bad user experience... for example, what happens when the user makes a typo and the text field ends editing?  Better would be to stop allowing extra input after the fractional limit is hit and make sure the keyboard has a done button so the user can decide when he/she is actually done entering data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would be a bad user experience if you dismissed the keyboard after 2 digits from the decimal place. (Also wouldn't work for fraction-less currencies, such as Yen).

To dismiss a keyboard like this, the easiest option would be to dismiss the keyboard when the user touches outside of the keyboard area. You could do this by applying a `UITapGestureRecognizer' on the view just behind the keyboard when bringing it up, then removing it once the keyboard is dismissed.

Comment: Auto-dismissal is also bad because the user can easily tap the wrong key and want to fix it but the keyboard is gone already. And what about cases such as pasting text or selecting text or moving the caret and entering text? A better approach is to add an `inputAccessoryView` to the keyboard with a Done button. Let the user choose when the keyboard goes away.

Comment: Ack! Good points. Not doing an auto dismissal. No room for a done button on the decimal pad keyboard, but I think I'll add one to the right side of the navigation item bar.

Comment: Adding a toolbar to go with the keyboard is another way to have a button to dismiss the keyboard.